# OpenVas report directory

Tags: openvas

Could anyone please tell me where the reports generated by the OpenVas is stored in harddrive. I know the report can be downloaded from the web interface, but I really need to know its location in directory.

I installed OpenVas 9 in Debian 9.
Also, why does my OPM get stuck in authentication process? I can not automate the scanning process.